# vertical align not working with table display

Tags: html, css

I've searched online for numerous solutions to this problem and I have not been able to solve my problem.

I am trying to vertically align a div within its parent, my markup can be seen below:

```
   <div class="section-content row">
       <div class="column grid_6">
            <h1 style="">amazing new content</h1>
            <p>here is some description</p>
       </div>
       <div class="column grid_6">
            <div class="video_overlay">
                <div class="button">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <figure>
                <img src="./public/img//sections/cam_5.png"/>
            </figure>
       </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.section-content {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 1680px !important;
}

.row {
   display: table !important;
   z-index: 2;
}

.row::after {
    clear: both;
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
   content: "";
   height: 100%;
}

.column {
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I thought by displaying the .column as a table-cell and vertically aligning it in the .row table it should vertically align the child, but it seems that it does not.

When I look in the inspector on my browser, the parent has a height of 500 and the child a height of 200, so I don't see why it is not aligning.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: seems to work to me ? http://www.bootply.com/ZvyoKfKfRB